# How to make simple ckeditor plugin?

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor

I uses the CKEditor. I'd like to make an incredibly simple plugin: when a user selects text and then hits MyPluginIcon, the editor surrounds the text in a mytag tag with a specific class.

So it's just like the Bold or Italic button, but for:

tata

I am far from a JS expert, so I have been looking for a plugin to copy. I cant get data from selected range :(. My code is:

```
        var cked = $("#" + part_id).ckeditorGet();
        var select = cked.getSelection();
        var ranges = select.getRanges( true );

        if ( ranges.length == 1 ) {
            range = ranges[0];
            var el = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( '<mytag"'+ $("#link").val() + '" >' + range.extractContents() + '</mytag>' );
            cked.insertElement(el);
        }
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some way given by CKEDITOR for defining custom style in [styes plugin](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles) [code](http://svn.fckeditor.net/CKEditor/trunk/_source/plugins/styles/plugin.js). And how to use that go to [basicstyles plugin](http://svn.fckeditor.net/CKEditor/trunk/_source/plugins/basicstyles/plugin.js). I think you will be benefited.